# JavaScript - setInterval function: interval won't clear

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, clearinterval

NOTE: I have viewed all questions and answers pertaining to setInterval / clearInterval and none of them have been any aid. Do not mark this as a duplicate.

I have an HTML page with an element whose background changes colors (from red to green to blue and so on). When it is clicked, the color should stop changing. I am using setInterval to run an updateCard() function that is supposed to check if the color is currently changing or not and either clear the interval or reset it. When clicked, it does not stop changing colors. I added console.log checks to see if the interval ID is changing and I discovered it was (my function was called update) so I fixed that. The interval ID is now the same when it is cleared as when it is defined. Here is my colorChange.js file that is embedded in my HTML.

```js
var titleCard = document.getElementById("titleCard"),
 red = 255,
 green = 255,
 blue = 255,
 redDir = 1,
 greenDir = -1,
 blueDir = -1,
 on = true,
 colorChange = setInterval(updateCard, 10);

function updateCard() {
 if (red > 255) red = 255;
 if (green > 255) green = 255;
 if (blue > 255) blue = 255;
 if (red < 0) red = 0;
 if (green < 0) green = 0;
 if (blue < 0) blue = 0;
 
 red += redDir;
 green += greenDir;
 blue += blueDir;
 
 if (red >= 255 && green <= 0 && blue <= 0) turnGreen();
 if (red <= 0 && green >= 255 && blue <= 0) turnBlue();
 if (red <= 0 && green <= 0 && blue >= 255) turnRed();
 
 titleCard.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," +  green + "," + blue + ")";
}

function turnRed() {
 redDir = 1;
 greenDir = -1;
 blueDir = -1;
}

function turnGreen() {
 redDir = -1;
 greenDir = 1;
 blueDir = -1;
}

function turnBlue() {
 redDir = -1;
 greenDir = -1;
 blueDir = 1;
}

titleCard.onclick = function() {
 if (on) {
  console.log("Clearing: " + colorChange);
  clearInterval(colorChange);
  on = false;
 } else {
  colorChange = setInterval(updateCard, 10);
  console.log("Set: " + colorChange);
  on = true;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple_icon.png"/>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/apple_icon.png"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/materialize.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="card hoverable">
    <h1 id="titleCard" class="card-content center">My Name</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col s4 push-s4">
    <div id="welcomeCard" class="card teal lighten-3">
     <p class="card-content center">Welcome to my website.<br/>Enjoy your stay.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="background1"></div>
 </body>
 <script src="/js/colorChange.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/changeTitle.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/style.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is an example from my console of the element being clicked 5 times:

```js
colorChange.js:50 Clearing: 61
colorChange.js:55 Set: 62
colorChange.js:50 Clearing: 62
colorChange.js:55 Set: 63
colorChange.js:50 Clearing: 63
```

This proves that the clearInterval call is clearing the correct ID. Why is the color still changing?

EDIT:
Hilariously, the snippet above actually functions properly. In my webpage, however, it does not. I'm more confused than before.

EDIT 2: I added my full HTML page.

EDIT 3:
Here are my other JS files, maybe there's an issue there?

changeTitle.js

```js
var titleCard = document.getElementById("titleCard");
 currentTime = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes(),
 today = new Date().getMonth() + 1 + "/" + new Date().getDate(),
 colorChange = setInterval(updateCard, 10);

function updateCard() {
 currentTime = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes();
 if (currentTime == "11:11" || currentTime == "23:11") changeTitle("Make a wish!", 1);
 else if (today == "2/13") changeTitle("Happy birthday to me", 1);
 else if (today == "12/11") changeTitle("Happy birthday, Kayla!", 1);
 else if (today == "3/7") changeTitle("Happy birthday, Nathan!", 1);
 else if (today == "1/1") changeTitle("Happy birthday, Mom!", 1);
 else if (today == "1/29") changeTitle("Happy birthday, Dad!", 1);
 else if (today == "8/3") changeTitle("Happy birthday, Brandon!", 1);
 else if (today == "7/24") changeTitle("Happy birthday, Dustin!", 1);
 else if (today == "11/23") changeTitle("Happy birthday, Branson!", 1);
 else if (today == "11/8") changeTitle("Happy birthday, Jack!", 1);
 else defaultTitle();
}

function changeTitle(body, interval) {
 titleCard.innerHTML = body;
 clearInterval(colorChange);
 colorChange = setInterval(updateCard, interval);
}

function defaultTitle() {
 titleCard.innerHTML = "MY NAME";
 clearInterval(colorChange);
 colorChange = setInterval(updateCard, 10);
}
```

style.js

```js
var background1 = document.getElementById("background1");
background1.style.position = "absolute";
background1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
background1.style.top = 0;
background1.style.left = 0;
background1.style.width = "100%";
background1.style.height = "25%";
background1.style.zIndex = -1;
```

This is killing me

FINAL EDIT: Solved, view @GregL's and @CodeiSir's answers.

Comment: I do not see anything running the snippet.

Comment: @frontend_dev I added my HTML to the snippet.

Comment: What Browser are you using?

Comment: FYI - snippet works fine in firefox

Comment: First snippet works fine in Chrome for me. Can you perhaps expand more on what you are doing, what happened, and what you expected to see?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same ID by any chance?

Comment: @GregL The snippet is working perfectly but on my webpage, it is not. I'm going to add my other JS files.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co) instead? That allows you to have multiple files, so you can include all your JS. The StackOverflow snippets don't allow multiple JS files (the `<script>` tags that refer to them don't point to valid JS files on the StackOverflow site).

Comment: @GregL sure thing, give me a minute

Comment: i think i found the problem, see my answer edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are redefining a number of key variables and functions in multiple JS files, so the latter values will overwrite the former values and cause the original values to be "lost".

This is because in Javascript, only functions create a new scope, so stuff outside of a function in any JS file will be in the global namespace.

However, you can use a technique called an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (usually pronounced "iffy") to make use of the fact that functions create new naming scope, thus isolating each code file from the other, and allowing everything to work.

Here is a [forked Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pB5HY9pkXvhaD4UWKk66?p=preview) with it working.

The core change was to add this line to the top of both JS files:

```
(function () {
```

and this line to the bottom of each JS file:

```
})();
```

EDIT: Credit must go to @CodeiSir, who found the problem was the reuse of variable and function names in both JS files.

Comment: Only if you return an object with the "exported" functions from the IIFE, yes. This is basically what is known as the [_revealing module pattern_](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/).

Answer (score 0):

I went through to code,

Here is a working example: (press RUN) (in case you wonder, `onclick` is fired when the mouse-button goes up on the same object it went down, so you might not have an imediat reaction, use `onmousedown` instead to see an imediat reaction)

```js
var titleCard = document.getElementById("titleCard"),
  red = 255,
  green = 255,
  blue = 255,
  redDir = 1,
  greenDir = -1,
  blueDir = -1,
  on = true,
  colorChange = setInterval(updateCard, 10);

function updateCard() {
  if (red > 255) red = 255;
  if (green > 255) green = 255;
  if (blue > 255) blue = 255;
  if (red < 0) red = 0;
  if (green < 0) green = 0;
  if (blue < 0) blue = 0;

  red += redDir;
  green += greenDir;
  blue += blueDir;

  if (red >= 255 && green <= 0 && blue <= 0) turnGreen();
  if (red <= 0 && green >= 255 && blue <= 0) turnBlue();
  if (red <= 0 && green <= 0 && blue >= 255) turnRed();

  titleCard.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
}

function turnRed() {
  redDir = 1;
  greenDir = -1;
  blueDir = -1;
}

function turnGreen() {
  redDir = -1;
  greenDir = 1;
  blueDir = -1;
}

function turnBlue() {
  redDir = -1;
  greenDir = -1;
  blueDir = 1;
}

titleCard.onclick = function() {
  if (on) {
    console.log("Clearing: " + colorChange);
    clearInterval(colorChange);
    on = false;
  } else {
    colorChange = setInterval(updateCard, 10);
    console.log("Set: " + colorChange);
    on = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="titleCard" style="height: 100px; width: 100px"></div>
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the Problem:
you are using the same variables in `changeTitle.js` again:

```
var titleCard = document.getElementById("titleCard");
    currentTime = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes(),
    today = new Date().getMonth() + 1 + "/" + new Date().getDate(),
    colorChange = setInterval(updateCard, 10);
```

you will have to use different variables for each of youre files

Comment: Look at my snippet, it works too. I'm going to add my full HTML to see if it's something there.

Comment: After the edit, it appears @CodeiSir has actually found the problem: the reassigning to the global `colorChange` variable, meaning the ID of the interval started in the first JS file is lost, and can never be cancelled.

Comment: I changed it to titleCard2 in changeTitle.js and it isn't working

Comment: Oh wait! Do I need to change colorChange as well?

Comment: the critical variable is `colorChange` as you are using it for two diffrent intervals

Comment: @HiiddeN You are actually overwriting quite a few variables in the two JS files, because they are all in the global namespace. You could surround both files with an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to have them local to the file, and then it should work.

Comment: yes, remember: global variables or functions with the same name, are the same on the complete website - independent of the file (you where also overwriting `function updateCard()` in both files). Also check out TypeScript sometime in the future, it's a nice support for making JavaScript-Code

Comment: @GregL this has done it! I encased each JS file in an IIFE and it works! Thanks!